# Unable to copy custom Object to Apache-CXF generated Object using Dozzer Mapper

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb, cxf

I am using Apache CXF (org.apache.cxf) maven plugin to auto generate Java files (wsdl2java) and want to copy the response object generated from the business logic to the auto generated file generated by Apache CXF using Dozer mapper. But Dozer mapper is unable to copy list object from source to target as setter method of list is not generated using the CXF plugin.

XSD File:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://com/test/ram/webservices/customer" targetNamespace="http://com/test/ram/webservices/customer" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="customerRequest" type="tns:customerRequestType" />
    <xs:complexType name="customerRequestType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CustomerID"                   type="xs:string"          minOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="customerResponse" type="tns:customerResponseType" />
    <xs:complexType name="customerResponseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="TemplateList"                                       minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Template"          type="xs:string"     minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>
                                        TemplateList.
                                </xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>   
</xs:schema>
```

pom.xml

```
org.apache.cxf plugin to generate wsdl2java
```

Custom Customer class:

```
public class customerResponse {   
    private customerResponse.TemplateList templateList;

    public customerResponse .TemplateList getTemplateList() {
        return templateList;
    }

    public void setTemplateList(customerResponse .TemplateList value) {
        this.templateList = value;
    }

    public static class TemplateList {
        private List<String> template;

        public List<String> getTemplate() {
            if (template == null) {
                template = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            return this.template;
        }

        public void setTemplate(List<String> tmp) {
            template=tmp
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerResponse object auto generated by CXF plugin

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "customerResponse", propOrder = {
    "templateList"
})
public class customerResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "TemplateList", required = true)
    protected customerResponse.TemplateList templateList;

    public customerResponse .TemplateList getTemplateList() {
        return templateList;
    }

    public void setTemplateList(customerResponse .TemplateList value) {
        this.templateList = value;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "template"
    })
    public static class TemplateList {

        @XmlElement(name = "Template")
        protected List<String> template;

        public List<String> getTemplate() {
            if (template == null) {
                template = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            return this.template;
        }

    }
}
```

Dozer mapper unable to copy TemplateList.

```
customerResponse response = dozerMapper.map(customerResponse, customerResponse.class);
```

So, is there a way to copy the list object using Dozer mapper in the absence of setter method in the auto generated java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution from following Reference Link now i can see generated java class has setter method for list.

```
 https://gist.github.com/meiwin/2779731
 https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3-support/issues/4
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>moc.scodma.tsacmoc.mra</groupId>
        <artifactId>mra</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>mra-messaging-schema</artifactId>


    <properties>
        <src.generated.dir>src/main/java</src.generated.dir>
        <artifact.cxf.version>3.1.6</artifact.cxf.version>
        <xerces.version>2.11.0</xerces.version>
        <inbound.wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/inbound/tsacmocService.wsdl</inbound.wsdl>
        <inbound.wsdl.location>classpath:resources/wsdl/inbound/tsacmocService.wsdl</inbound.wsdl.location>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${artifact.cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${src.generated.dir}</sourceRoot>
                            <defaultOptions>
                                <noAddressBinding>true</noAddressBinding>
                                <faultSerialVersionUID>3105839350746982386</faultSerialVersionUID>
                            </defaultOptions>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${inbound.wsdl}</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>${inbound.wsdl.location}</wsdlLocation>
                                    <serviceName>mraService</serviceName>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-Xts</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-Xcollection-setter-injector</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>http://tsacmoc.ent.moc/mra/=moc.ent.tsacmoc.mra</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>http://tsacmoc.ent.moc/mocmonheader/=moc.ent.tsacmoc.mocmonheader</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                        <version>${xerces.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.java.dev.vcc.thirdparty</groupId>
                            <artifactId>collection-setter-injector</artifactId>
                            <version>0.5.0-1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>moc.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>moc.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

java :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "template"
    })
    public static class TemplateList {

        @XmlElement(name = "Template")
        protected List<String> template;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the template property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the template property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getTemplate().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link String }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<String> getTemplate() {
            if (template == null) {
                template = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            return this.template;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the template property.
         * 
         * @param template
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setTemplate(List<String> template) {
            this.template = template;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB2 Setters Plugin which generates setter methods.

The plugin is activated by the `-Xsetters` command line option.
You can also use the `-Xsetters-mode=accessor` or `-Xsetters-mode=direct` options to configure the generation modes.

Refer below maven example to configure this plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version><!-- Current version --></version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-XtoString</arg>
            <arg>-Xequals</arg>
            <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
            <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
            <arg>-Xmergeable</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version><!-- Current version --></version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also add below dependency in your pom.xml because generated code depends on it.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
        <version><!-- Current version --></version>
</dependency>
```

Refer this [link](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Setters+Plugin) for more help. Also, there is a [user guide](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/User+Guide) which might be helpful.